# What is the right way to select records from mongodb document

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, database, nosql

I"m new in **mongodb** and I really like the idea of noSql.

I"m trying to build a blog where on each comment people can click on rate buttons and rate the person comment.

Inside each comment I have a array of votes where there is a vote type and unique IP.
Each user click on button will insert line (once per IP).

**At the end I want to query documents/posts and get the information in the following structure, CalculatedVotes, distinct VoteType, Caption and count**

**The result that I want to retrieve**

```
   {
    PostTitle:"This is a blog post",
    Posted:"12/12/2012",
    ByUsertId:"2",
    Body:"This is a simple body"
    Comments:
    [
        {
            PostedBy:"someUser",
            Text:"Hi There!",
            CalculatedVotes:
            [
                {
                    VoteType:"AGREE",
                    Caption="I agree!",
                    Count:2
                },
                {
                    VoteType:"NOT_AGREE",
                    Caption="No Way!",
                    Count:1
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            PostedBy:"someUser2",
            Text:"Whats up?",
            CalculatedVotes:
            [
                {
                    VoteType:"AGREE",
                    Caption="I agree!",
                    Count:1
                },
                {
                    VoteType:"NOT_AGREE",
                    Caption="No Way!",
                    Count:2
                },
            ]
        }
    ]

    }
```

**Document structure**

```
{
    PostTitle:"This is a blog post",
    Posted:"12/12/2012",
    ByUsertId:2,
    Body:"This is a simple body"
    Comments:
    [
        {
            PostedBy:"someUser",
            Text:"Hi There!",
            Votes:
            [
                {
                    VoteType:"AGREE",
                    Caption="I agree!",
                    IP:"1.1.1.1"
                },
                 {
                    VoteType:"NOT_AGREE",
                    Caption="No Way!",
                    IP:"2.2.2.2"
                },
                 {
                    VoteType:"AGREE",
                    Caption="I agree!",
                    IP:"3.3.3.3"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            PostedBy:"someUser2",
            Text:"Whats up?",
            Votes:
            [
                {
                    VoteType:"NOT_AGREE",
                    Caption="No Way!",
                    IP:"1.1.1.1"
                },
                 {
                    VoteType:"NOT_AGREE",
                    Caption="No Way!",
                    IP:"2.2.2.2"
                },
                 {
                    VoteType:"AGREE",
                    Caption="I agree!",
                    IP:"3.3.3.3"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

}
```

Comment: I hope you don't expect too many comments as your blog post document is going to bloat if you always embed everything into it.  Just because it's noSQL doesn't mean that some things shouldn't be stored in their own separate collection.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that best is to reconsider your schema.  A good example of storing hierarchy is described [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/use-cases/category-hierarchy/).

In your schema you will run into multiple issues, not the least of them that if a discussion gets very long you will end up with a huge document that will eventually exceed maximum document size (16MB).  In addition you will need to fetch only some of the document but you will always be getting the huge complete discussion even when you don't want it (and it will be difficult to filter on the bases of depth of embedded structure).

Last but not least, the best way to handle counting is to be incrementing the vote count in real time as you are recording the votes to avoid the overhead of recalculating them and that has the added benefit that you can order by votes or even index by votes if needed.

Comment: Thank you, you right about incrementing the vote count in real time, however how can I prevent not unique hits?

Comment: you can have a unique constraint on voter's ip combined with blog post's id.  So each IP can only vote for each blog once... I'm sure there are other ways to do it.